# Trivial class group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $$I_k=\lbrace  ideals \ \  in  \ \ \mathcal{O_k}\rbrace $$

and $$ P_k=\lbrace   principal \ \ ideals \ \  in  \ \ \mathcal{O_k}\rbrace \subset I_k$$

unique factorisation would follow from the equality $I_k=P_k$ .

One can also define this for fractional ideals :
$$F_k=\lbrace   fractional \ \ ideals \ \  in  \ \ \mathcal{O_k}\rbrace $$

and$$PF_k=\lbrace principal \ \ fractional \ \   ideals \ \  in  \ \ \mathcal{O_k}\rbrace $$

The class group is defined as $C_k=F_k/PF_k$

If the class group is trivial then $F_k=PF_k$ .

Why does it then follow that $I_k=P_k$ ?

Comment: Because ideals are also fractional ideals...